# Grails 'method not allowed' weirdness

Tags: grails, url-routing, grails-2.0, http-status-code-405

I have simple controller code like:

```
// UserController.groovy

class UserController {

    static allowedMethods = [
            signIn:       'GET',
            authenticate: 'POST',
            signOut:      'POST',
            register:     'GET',
            save:         'POST'
    ]

    // ... code omitted

    def register() { }

    def save() {
        render 'ok'
    }
}
```

Registration form:

```
<!-- register.gsp -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <title>Withme: Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <g:form mapping="register">
        <!-- Code omitted -->
        <g:actionSubmit value="Register" />
    </g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

And url mappings:

```
//UrlMappings.groovy

class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = { 
        name register: '/register'(controller: 'user') {
            action = [GET: 'register', POST: 'save']
        }
    }
}
```

Now for the weird part. When making request with curl all works as expected:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/withme/register -X GET -v -L
... form rendered ...

$ curl http://localhost:8080/withme/register -X POST -v -L
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2013 07:41:23 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
ok* Closing connection #0
```

Accessing /register with a browser returns form. But when I submit it within a browser, 405 returned!

```
HTTP Status 405 -

type Status report

message

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

Firebug confirms that POST is performed:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/withme/register | 405 Method Not Allowed | localhost:8080
```

I have disabled all filters in my application.

I wonder what the difference between curl and browser POST requests? Why grails handles it in a different way? And finally, how to fix it..

Grails 2.2.4 Groovy Version: 2.1.6 JVM: 1.7.0_21 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

**Update**

I've figured out that request body matters. Sending request with curl without body succeed, but setting body causes request to fail. Good one:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/withme/register -X POST -v -L
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /withme/register HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2013 09:39:22 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
ok* Closing connection #0
```

And bad one:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/withme/register -X POST -v -L -d "email=&password=&passwordConfirmation=&firstName=&lastName=&country=&city=&_action_Register=Register"
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /withme/register HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 100
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 100 out of 100 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 977
< Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2013 09:40:31 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 405 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.42</h3></body></html>* Closing connection #0
```

Still what's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved strange problem.

Grails renders `<g:actionSubmit value="Register" />` as

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="_action_Register">
```

Note the strange name. Grails deduce it from the `value` attribute and uses it when choosing what action to call. It causes problem in my case because `POST /register` should be handled by `save` action.

Changing it to `<input type="submit" value="Register">` solve the problem.

Comment: Interesting, but if you have a form with the correct action, just use `g:submitButton`. As you figured out, `g:actionSubmit` will create this magic name and submit your form to another action (use when you need submit action != form action).

Comment: I wouldn't call it a strange problem - that's how it works [per documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html).